# GoogleSheet value search conditioned by approximate match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hope you're coping with confinement wherever you are.

I'm having some difficulties with a GoogleSheet operation I'd like to do and can't find any suitable solution on the web.

I'm aiming to compare values (decimal numbers) in columns in two separate tables (I'll call table 1 column A and table 2 column C) and obtain the corresponding cell value in another column of the second table (table 2 column E).
Besides, the search is also conditioned by the a corresponding date(month) of the values in both tables (in table 1 column B and table 2 column D).
I've come up to here with a simple INDEX(MATCH()) formula applied in all lines of the table 1 sheet :

`=index(table2!A:E;match(A1&month(B1);table2!C:C&month(table2!D:D);0);5)`

The twist is that values in A and C are sometimes not exactly the same, they can have a slight difference in decimals, but I still want the match to work. I've tried using `STDEV(X;Y)<0,1` inside the INDEX(MATCH()) or a way of using this kind of formula `IF(AND(X<=Y+0,1;X>=Y-0,1)` but was unsuccessful.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions in doing an efficient search with two conditions with an approximate match for one of them ?
(I have basic knowledge of QUERY functions if this can be done with that too.)

Hope I've been clear enough.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you try using round function - depending on your accuracy need.

Comment: Hi lostin, I did actually, but my decimal numbers have a negative sign in one table and a positive sign in the other making the roundup function provide different results (especially in the case of a 0,5 decimal)

Comment: Can you share some data to reproduce the  issue ?

Comment: You can try round , abs and some kind of if condition to do this.

Comment: I've just done a quick simplified version of the gsheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NbtK7Vr1RXS9VYTK0hUlSTW7ohVqaXnVtc3C90pglLI/edit#gid=0

As you can see both roundup and rounddown functions don't bring the same result.
It seems long decimal values don't help, but these values are imported from calculation so the number of decimals can vary quite a lot from one to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Roundup and Rounddown, using Round and Abs worked for me.

Not working consistently.

```
 = index($F$2:$H;match(ROUNDDOWN(-$B2;1)&month($A2);ROUNDDOWN($G$2:$G;1)&month($F$2:$F);0);3)
```

This worked for me.    `=index($F$2:$H;match(ROUND(abs($B2);1)&month($A2);ROUND($G$2:$G;1)&month($F$2:$F);0);3)`

See if this works for your all data. You may need to include if condition if values could be negative/positive in your left table.

Without if condition this also may work -

```
index($F$4:$H;match(ROUNDup(abs($B4);$B$1)&month($A4);ROUNDup(abs($G$4:$G);$B$1)&month($F$4:$F);0);3)
```

Comment: So this did help for most of the values but I remember trying something like that previously and it didn't always round in the same way.

_For example : 1,050 and 1,046 with a ROUND() set at 1 will result in 1,1 for the first value and 1,0._
This would work for a ROUND() set at 2 but it would affect other values with lesser decimals. I edited the gsheet I shared to show what happens when juggling with B1 cell (number of decimals to round).

Maybe a way would be to check the difference between the round of both values but I can't seem to integrate it in the complete formula with an IF().